# how to compare and validate textbox value with listview cell value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms, listview

I want to validate my textbox value with listview cell value. I want to not add greater value than available quantity in list view. I tried alot but no solution found, on stackoverflow and many other sites. plz help me if anyone have solutions.
below is my code
if (ListView1.Items.Count==0)
{

```
                ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
                lst.SubItems.Add(txtProductID.Text);
                lst.SubItems.Add(txtProductName.Text);
                lst.SubItems.Add(txtPrice.Text);
                lst.SubItems.Add(txtSaleQty.Text);
                lst.SubItems.Add(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                ListView1.Items.Add(lst);
                txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
              
                Calculate();
                txtProductName.Text = "";
                txtProductID.Text = "";
                txtPrice.Text = "";
                txtAvailableQty.Text = "";
                txtSaleQty.Text = "";
                txtTotalAmount.Text = "";
                txtProduct.Text = "";
                return;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text == txtProductID.Text)
                {
                    ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text = txtProductID.Text;
                    ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text = txtProductName.Text;
                    ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[3].Text = txtPrice.Text;
                    ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[4].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[4].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtSaleQty.Text)).ToString();
                    ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[5].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[5].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalAmount.Text)).ToString();
                    txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
                    Calculate();
                    txtProductName.Text = "";
                    txtProductID.Text = "";
                    txtPrice.Text = "";
                    txtAvailableQty.Text = "";
                    txtSaleQty.Text = "";
                    txtTotalAmount.Text = "";
                    return;

                }
            }
               
                ListViewItem lst1 = new ListViewItem();

                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtProductID.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtProductName.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtPrice.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtSaleQty.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                ListView1.Items.Add(lst1);
                txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
                Calculate();
                txtProductName.Text = "";
                txtProductID.Text = "";
                txtPrice.Text = "";
                txtAvailableQty.Text = "";
                txtSaleQty.Text = "";
                txtTotalAmount.Text = "";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: is this desktop or web based? You have this tagged as asp.net, and the asp.net ListView does not have a .subItems[] property. So, if this is desktop, then remove the asp.net tag. and if this really is web based, then the standard ListView does not have a subItems property of the ListViewItem. So, does this code even compile then?

Comment: this is desktop app i compiled it, it work fine but i want to not add qty greater than available qty in list view